# How do you run your PHP Cakephp code in local machine with Codelobster IDE

Tags: php, testing, cakephp, ide

If using Codelobster IDE with its Cakephp plugin ( on wamp server )  - how could the code be tested locally - in the local machine before going live,

or what options are for running the code and database queries locally

Comment: Look into the preferences area to specify your dev machine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the CodeLobster forum?

http://codelobster.com/forum/search.php?keywords=cakephp&terms=all&author=&sc=1&sf=all&sk=t&sd=d&sr=posts&st=0&ch=300&t=0&submit=Search

I don't really see what your problem is, though. Just copy your files to the **htdocs** folder (or whatever it's called in your *AMP - maybe **www** or **Documents**) and fire it up in the browser (http://localhost/MyProject). I keep all my projects in that folder - really, it's the only way to develop.